# How To Block Skype using Squid3?

Tags: proxy, squid

I have just installed Squid3 on my server and trying to block the Skype messenger. Still no luck. I tried to add the rules in Squid wiki (http://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/Chat/Skype) to the end of the squid.conf :

```
# Skype

 acl numeric_IPs dstdom_regex ^(([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)|(\[([0-9af]+)?:([0-9af:]+)?:([0-9af]+)?\])):443
 acl Skype_UA browser ^skype

 http_access deny numeric_IPS
 http_access deny Skype_UA

 acl validUserAgent browser \S+
 http_access deny !validUserAgent
```

But none works. How to block Skype? Please help

Comment: I suggest you sniff some Skype traffic with filddler2 to find out what it looks like. Skype and similar tend to change their signature over time to evade proxy filters.

Comment: I think skype is one of the messagers which traffic cannot be sniffed/blocked that way...

Comment: Just to be sure, check if these rules are applied. If it is a matching rule with allow before them in squid.conf they will not be applied.

Comment: Did you see http://serverfault.com/questions/127605